# Free Windows program to convert video from VOB

Tags: windows, gratis, video, file-converter

As the tile says, I am looking for a gratis Windows program to convert video from VOB.

Preferred output format is MKV or MP4, but I will accept any common Widows format (AVI, etc).

Please recommend something which you use yourself.

A batch mode, recursing through sub-directories, would be a bonus.

As would the ability to darken/lighten, change contrast and adjust volume.

---

[Update] please, no time-limits, no size limits, no watermarks. Totally gratis, convert a `VIDEO_TS` directory on harddrive to video + audio.

Handbrake only converts the first section.
Any Video Converter is not converting the audio.

I will offer a bonus, 50 points to kick it off, but maybe more if I get a great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative  [TEncoder Video Converter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tencoder/). TEncoder  is a GUI video converter that uses either FFmpeg or MEncoder as its back end. Unlike Ffmpeg which  is a command-line utility, it provides a GUI and is much easier to use.

Features (not exhaustive)

> - Run up to 16 simultaneous processes and/or make FFMpeg and Mencoder to do internal multithreaded encoding.
> - Rip unprotected DVDs
> - Hard-code subtitles with same name as video using Mencoder
> - Hard-code subtitles tracks (soft-coded subtitles) with MEncoder

[image]

*License: Free / Open Source (GPL) and other OSI licenses*

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Comment: I had an older version of this on my drive (URL now points another app - maybe its successor?). It reported one error, so I am rerunning it. What I don't like is that it generated one MKV file for each input VOB, so I would need a separate app to join the outputs into a single file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) for just about any video conversion tasks including this.

An example command line would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input -acodec libfaac -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1200k -mbd 2 -flags+mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -metadata title=X output.mp4
```

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Command line
- Can be used from batch files
- Windows, OS-X & Linux.

To get it to work recursively you are going to need some more advanced scripting than Windows really supports but you could use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to gather the information required for the ffmpeg invocation.  Python may be a good solution for putting together a script to locate the VOB files, use ffprobe to extract the required information and output it to an ffmpeg command.

Comment: Upvote. Might even accept as answer, if there were a good GUI

Answer (score 0):

As @steave-barnes mentioned FFMpeg is one of best free and opensources for video convertion.
I found [qwinff](https://qwinff.github.io/) as windows interface for it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For VOB Files (you can select multiple files) I use [FFmpegYAG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegyag/) which is a GUI for ffmpeg 
For VIDEO_TS I am using VLC Media Player \

[image: Image of FFmpegYAG]

Press "Add Task(s)" and a Explorer Windows opens, now you can open as many Files as you want, then select Format, in your case its "matroska" (mkv). Then press "Encode" and it gets converted. 
If you could provide a VOB File with Audio and all your needs I could test it for you

Comment: I actually have both *.vob and VIDEO_TS - not sure what they are. I just guesses video & audio. Mp4 is fine, although MKV is better. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot showing how to import/open a VOB? Then a brief description of what buttons to click etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far, none of these work, so I suspect my VOB input.

Handbrake seems to be working on another input, so I am happy enough with that. It even joined all sections into a single file. I wil try the others, one by one, and eventually award an answer - but I am too busy to do so before the system automatically awards the bounty. Sorry